# Ajax request to the same jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax

Pardon me if my terminologies are not exact. Here is my situation

1) I want to make an ajax request using a jQuery to the same jsp ( a.jsp)

Meaning a.jsp has the jQuery ajax calling the same a.jsp. Is this possible?

2) A function in my jsp outputs a JSON based on the context of the tool ( Portal).
Can the ajax request be made for this function on the page passing different parameters?

3) The idea is to do something like the "more info" meaning clicking more info will load the same jsp and pass different parameters to the function so that next set of results are fetched. Also I need to filter the results before being displayed.

Anyway I am not sure if I explained correct. Please give me some inputs

Comment: Why can't you modify or wrap the function that generates the json instead of making another request to the server?

Comment: I Would refer to the jquery function getJSON() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I dont want a huge result set that may cause performance issues on our end. We may receive more than 50000 records for a generic query without a indexed query ( start index to end index)